# How do you erase a Blackberry without having direct access to the server?

Tags: mobile, deletion, blackberry

I have a Blackberry with no access to the BIS or BES server that managed it.

How does one erase and reset the device to defaults?

Comment: related: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/2085/what-is-your-process-for-wiping-a-lost-blackberry-or-similar-device

Answer (score 2, accepted):

... just found something that works:

1. If you are an ordinary BIS user, perform a security wipe: Options / Security Options / General Settings / Menu / Wipe Handheld. If you are a BES admin, wipe using this procedure to remove the IT Policy: [Removing an IT Policy from a BlackBerry phone](http://forums.crackberry.com/f2/removing-policy-blackberry-phone-81401/).
2. Format or remove any Media card. Wiping the device does not delete data on the card.
3. Contact your carrier and release your pin.
4. Remove your phone number using Step 4a or 4b as appropriate.
   4a. GSM users: Remove your SIM. That takes your phone number out of your device.
   4b. CDMA users: Dial ##000000 and press Send. Delete the Mobile Directory Number and replace it with another 10-digit number that won't violate anyone's privacy. 2025551212 is a good choice. Then press the BB button and select Save. Allow the phone to reboot.

Alternatives that also wipe the device:

1. [CrackUtil](http://forums.crackberry.com/f35/crackutil-85617/)
2. [JLCmder](http://www.blackberryfreaks.com/JL_Cmder.html)

The following URL describes how to use the RIM utility "loader" to reset to defaults

http://www.blackberry.com/btsc/search.do?cmd=displayKC&docType=kc&externalId=KB18998

Lastly, the following key combination only reboots the phone and doesn't wipe the device (which is what lead me to researching this topic):

```
alt  +  right shift  + del
```